# をも: Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: particle-を, particle-も

> 日本で英語を教えたい。彼も教えたい。
>
> I want to teach English in Japan. He also wants to teach.

But if I were referring to myself in both sentences and talking about two different activities that I want to do:

> 日本で英語を教えたい。(1) **私も**書道を勉強したい。(2) 書道**をも**勉強したい。
>
> I want to teach English in Japan. I also want to learn calligraphy.

I'm not sure if (1) is the right way to go because it's like saying, "Me too" but I'm not referring to anyone else in the previous sentence. Is (2) grammatically correct? What's the correct way to write the second sentence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can say:

> 日本で英語を教えたい。書道**の**勉強**も**したい。

which literally means "I want to teach English in Japan. I want to do the study of calligraphy, too."

You could also say:

> 日本で英語を教えたい。書道**も**勉強したい。or 書道**も**[習]{なら}いたい。

where も is replacing を. (書道**をも** is grammatically correct but sounds literary and maybe a bit archaic.)

You're right that (1) 私**も**書道を勉強したい is like saying "Someone's learning calligraphy and I want to do that, too."

Comment: 'Literary' > 'literally', n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @l'électeur うわ間違えた。フランス語わからんってば。ドイツ語でいうて！

Comment: 独語て・・昭和っぽい人やな。今、独語やる人少ないねん。間違いが直ったから+1や。がんばりや！

Comment: The first and second examples have subtly different meaning, no? The former is what you said; the latter implies there are other (as yet unmentioned, inasmuch as teaching is separate from studying) things the speaker would like to study, calligraphy being one of them.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes I know what you mean, the 2nd one can imply what you said, as in 「日本語を**勉強**しています / したいと思っています。書道**も**勉強したいです。」 but actually in normal conversation we often use this kind of phrase (noun+も+verb) to list different activities with different verbs too, as in 「京都に行ったら、伏見稲荷に行きたい。金閣寺**も**見たい。嵐山の湯豆腐**も**食べたいし、宇治の抹茶**も**飲んでみたい。」 (probably because も cannot be directly attached to verbs)