# Omitting the particle? 「時の経つのも忘れさせる」

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-も

> 明快な口調とテンポの良い楽しい授業が時の経つのも忘れさせる。

Ｗhen I searched the Internet I found the phrase `時の経つのを忘れさせる`.

So, what is the reason for replacing the particle を with も?

Comment: Why not use も? What do you think this sentence means? Why do you think the replacement would be a problem? Are you aware that も replaces を rather than using をも?

Comment: – user3856370 @ So, you mean to say that も indicates direct object of action ?

Comment: It can do. When you want to add a sense of 'even' or 'also' to the object of the sentence you **replace** を with も rather than adding it as an extra particle.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike English "also", the particle も can be used when there is no explicit "similar" thing specified in the context. In such cases, も is closer to "even". Either way, the basic rule is も **replaces** を (and が, は).

> - 笑っている人もいた。 There are even laughing people.
> - 天才もミスをする。 Even a genius makes mistakes.
> - 時が経つのを忘れた。 I forgot about the (passage of) time.
> - 時が経つの**も**忘れた。 I forgot *even* about the (passage of) time.

Keeping を and saying 時が経つの**をも**忘れさせる is actually grammatical, too, but it sounds fairly stilted. See:

- [をも: Is this sentence grammatically correct?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30945/5010)
- [をも.... what on earth is this particle combination?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13405/5010)